# Django and PostgresSQL are not connected?

Tags: python, postgresql, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a Django project with a PostgresSQL DB configured to it. In addition to that, I have a python script that connects to the DB and inserts or does queries on it (and it succeeds).
I can see the data on the DB when I connect locally to the server, and python also sees it. But, my Django website is completely empty. Also, I checked to see in my views.py file what queries Django receive and they return EMPTY.

Is there a configuration that I'm missing? Why when I worked on my SQLite DB everything was ok, and now when I transferred to Postgres there's no data? help please, I'm going nuts over this.

This is how my website looks(there's no data in the columns...)-

[image]

These are my configuration files-

**Views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import loader
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import ToExcel
from datetime import datetime


def index(request):
  group_names = ToExcel.objects.all()
  group_count = ToExcel.objects.count()
  index_list = [i+1 for i in range(group_count)]
  combined_list = zip(group_names, index_list)
  template = loader.get_template('index.html')
  context = {
    'group_data': combined_list,
  }
  return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))


def add(request):
  template = loader.get_template('add.html')
  return HttpResponse(template.render({}, request))


def addrecord(request):
  group = request.POST['group']
  heb_street = 'רחוב, ברובע'
  heb_sale_rent = 'מכירה, השכרה'
  heb_city = 'שכונת, בסמטאות'
  heb_rooms = 'חדרים'
  heb_size = 'מ״ר, מ"ר'
  heb_floor = 'קומה'
  heb_porch = 'מרפסת'
  heb_storage = 'מחסן'
  heb_mamad = 'ממד, ממ״ד'
  heb_parking = 'חניה, חנייה, חניית, חנית'
  heb_elevator = 'מעלית'
  heb_price = 'מחיר, מבקשים'
  heb_phone = '054, 052, 053'
  date = datetime.now().strftime('%d %b %Y')
  group = ToExcel(group_name=group, sale_rent=heb_sale_rent, street=heb_street, city=heb_city, rooms=heb_rooms, size=heb_size, floor=heb_floor, elevator=heb_elevator, porch=heb_porch, storage=heb_storage, mamad=heb_mamad, parking=heb_parking, price=heb_price, phone=heb_phone, user_date=date)
  group.save()
  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))


def delete(request, id):
  group = ToExcel.objects.get(id=id)
  group.delete()
  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))


def update(request, id):
  group = ToExcel.objects.get(id=id)
  template = loader.get_template('update.html')
  context = {
    'group': group,
  }
  return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))


def updaterecord(request, id):
  group_name = request.POST['group']
  sale_rent = request.POST['sale_rent']
  street = request.POST['street']
  city = request.POST['city']
  rooms = request.POST['rooms']
  size = request.POST['size']
  floor = request.POST['floor']
  porch = request.POST['porch']
  storage = request.POST['storage']
  mamad = request.POST['mamad']
  elevator = request.POST['elevator']
  parking = request.POST['parking']
  price= request.POST['price']
  phone= request.POST['phone']
  date = request.POST['user_date']
  group = ToExcel.objects.get(id=id)
  group.group_name = group_name
  group.sale_rent = sale_rent
  group.street = street
  group.city = city
  group.rooms = rooms
  group.size = size
  group.floor = floor
  group.porch = porch
  group.storage = storage
  group.mamad = mamad
  group.elevator = elevator
  group.parking = parking
  group.price = price
  group.phone = phone
  group.user_date = date
  group.save()
  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

**This is my settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for OrAvivi project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""
import os
from pathlib import Path
import import_export

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
# SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-5e4i+v)$-9qxr817a3^96k-0t^&(9^7xn#dr9+4o^15tkoue9n'
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY', 'cg#p$g+j9tax!#a3cup@1$8obt2_+&k3q+pmu)5%asj6yjpkag')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
# DEBUG = True
DEBUG = True


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'to_excel.apps.ToExcelConfig',
    'import_export',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'OrAvivi.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'OrAvivi.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'my_db',
        'USER': 'sql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'sql_user',
        'HOST': '192.168.72.130',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'to_excel/static'
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

**my main form**

```
{% load static %}

<h1>Group Search Words
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
</h1>


<table border="1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Group Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Deal Type</th>
        <th scope="col">Street</th>
        <th scope="col">City</th>
        <th scope="col">Rooms</th>
        <th scope="col">Size</th>
        <th scope="col">Floor</th>
        <th scope="col">Elevator</th>
        <th scope="col">Porch</th>
        <th scope="col">Storage</th>
        <th scope="col">Mamad</th>
        <th scope="col">Parking</th>
        <th scope="col">Price</th>
        <th scope="col">Phone</th>
        <th scope="col">Date</th>
    <tr>
    {% for x,y in group_data %}
    <tr>
    <td><a href="update/{{ x.id }}">{{ y }}</a></td>
    <td>{{ x.group_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.sale_rent }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.street }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.city }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.rooms }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.size }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.floor }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.elevator }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.porch }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.storage }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.mamad }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.parking }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.price }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.phone }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.user_date }}</td>
    <td><a href="delete/{{ x.id }}">delete</a></td>
</tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>


<h2> Made By Karin Pitlik 2022
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
</h2>
```

This is my DB:
[image]

Comment: so this: `ToExcel.objects.all()` returns an empty list to `group_names`?

Comment: yeah that's right!

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the right database? Why have you used IP '192.168.72.130' instead of 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1'? Have you used the same code to add data to this database?

Comment: group in PostgreSQL is keyword. If you have, for example, table that named like this, you must quote it with apostrophes in SQL query.

Comment: @babis21My mistake, I've changed the code on my Pycharm but on my server, it is a local host :-) I didn't try to add data with the shell if thats what you are asking

Comment: @RabbanKeyak oh ok, can you please tell me more about it??

Comment: I've added how my DB looks right now